# Not able to write in a file(python)

Tags: python, class, file-handling, httpserver

I'm trying to make an HTTP Server from scratch and wanted to write the log in a text file so I created this function.

```
    def do_LOG(self, addr, request):
    path = 'log/logging.txt'
    host = addr[0]
    port = addr[1]
    method = request[:4]
    headers = request.split('\n')
    filename = headers[0].split()[1]

    f = open(path, "a+")
    f.writelines('Server used: ' + host + '\n'+'Port used: ' + port + '\n'+'Method Served: ' + method + '\n'+'Filename: ' + filename + '\n\n')
    f.close()
    return
```

This function only creates a file but is not able to write in the file. I'm overriding this function from the parent class.This  is the definition in the parent class.

```
    def do_LOG(self, addr, request):
      return
```

Comment: You could save yourself the trouble of having to debug code that is peripheral to what you want to achieve by using Python's `logging` module instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please Provide some more code
2. For better handling, add relative path of the directory by adding './' at the start.
3. Make Sure the 'log' directory exists in the project's parent directory
4. Still I'm providing a temporary fix-

   ```
    class Logs:
        def do_LOG(self, addr, request):
            path = './log/logging.txt'
            host = addr[0]
            port = addr[1]
            method = request[:4]
            headers = request.split('\n')
            filename = headers[0].split()[1]

            f = open(path, "a+")
            f.writelines('Server used: ' + host + '\n'+'Port used: ' + port + '\n'+'Method Served: ' + method + '\n'+'Filename: ' + filename + '\n\n')
            f.close()
            return

    Logs().do_LOG("<addr>", "<request>")
   ```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

First, be careful to use proper indentation (I suspect this is from copying your code).

Second, you chose the mode 'a+' which I don't know about. In order to write to a file, you should use the 'w' mode, I also recommend providing the encoding:

```
f = open(path, "w", encoding= "utf-8")
f.write('Server used: ' + host + '\nPort used: ' + port + '\n'+'Method Served: ' + method + '\n'+'Filename: ' + filename + '\n\n')
f.close()
```

If this does not work, maybe that's because there is a problem with the values of `host`, `port` or `method`, you should then try to write the file with multiple calls, to see where the problem occurs:

```
f.write('Server used')
f.write(host)
...
```

Comment: Brother, the 'a+' mode in python is for creating a new file or opening an existing file for reading and writing, with file pointer positioned at the end of the file